# switching off wifi results in two times call to onReceive()

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, receiver

I am using Broadcast receiver for Internet availability.
Here is the code

```
private BroadcastReceiver mConnReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        boolean noConnectivity = intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, false);
        String reason = intent.getStringExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_REASON);
        boolean isFailover = intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_IS_FAILOVER, false);

        NetworkInfo currentNetworkInfo = (NetworkInfo) intent.getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
        NetworkInfo otherNetworkInfo = (NetworkInfo) intent.getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_OTHER_NETWORK_INFO);

        if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
            // Internet Connection is not present
            alert.showAlertDialog(DashBoardActivity.this,
                    "Internet Connection Error",
                    "Please connect to working Internet connection", false);
            // stop executing code by return
            return;
        }

        if(currentNetworkInfo.isConnected()){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not Connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
};

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();

    this.registerReceiver(this.mConnReceiver,
            new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "In resume", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

When I switch on the WiFi onReceive is called only once but when I switch off the WiFi onReceive is called twice because of that pop up or Toast used in above code appears twice.

Can anyone help on this strange error?

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) context
                        .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        activeNetworkInfo = connManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isAvailable()) {a
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Connected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not Connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
    }
```

Comment: Still the same effect

Comment: remove registerReceiver on onResume() ,put this to your onCreate().

Comment: do registerReceiver in Oncreate();

Comment: It doesnt make any difference

Answer (score 0):

I guess you've not unregistered the receiver whenever your activity is getting paused.

Add this to your Activity

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();

    this.unregisterReceiver(this.mConnReceiver);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "In pause", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: when I am on the same screen and switching off and switching on the router this bug comes.And also if i am directly switch off and switch on wifi from status bar.So in short it is not going in `onPause()`.When I am navigating in application it goes in `onPause` and may be because of that it comes for once only in case wifi off.so what is the problem?

Comment: @Bunny Put a `Log.d(...)` inside your `onReceive` and check again whether it logs to logcat twice or not.

Comment: As I'm not doing any changes so why should I put `Log.d(...)` and check again.what will happen if I put this?It's gonna give same result I guess.

Comment: @Bunny So, how did you find the `onReceive` is called twice?

Answer (score 0):

> As I understand There may be More than one State of WiFi when we
>   switchoff wifi in Device.
>
> Check the states of wifi using Following code and take action accordingly:

```
int extraWifiState = intent.getIntExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_WIFI_STATE, WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_UNKNOWN);

    switch (extraWifiState)
    {
    case WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_DISABLED:
    case WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_DISABLING:
        enableUI(false);
        break;
    case WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLED:
        ConnectivityManager conMan = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE); 
        while(conMan.getActiveNetworkInfo() == null || conMan.getActiveNetworkInfo().getState() != NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
        {
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        update();
        enableUI(true);
        break;
    case WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLING:
        break;
    case WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_UNKNOWN:
        break;
    }

}
```

> may it help You to find out to solution for your problem.

Comment: What are `enableUI(false);` `enableUI(true);` and `update();` in the above code?

Comment: Whether it is switched on or off it is going in `case WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_UNKNOWN:` case.what is the problem?

Comment: sorry, just ignore it. Remove it and try again @Bunny

Comment: you are not able to get WIFI_STATE

Comment: Is this the problem with specific phone?

Comment: can not say. may be your intentFilter you are using at time of register the Receiver. can you please provide intent filter you are using.

Comment: I am using getActivity().registerReceiver(WifiStateChangedReceiver,
    new IntentFilter(WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION)); and in manifest add two permissions <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />  working fine for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90320/discussion-between-hradesh-kumar-and-bunny).